# Cocos2D 2.0 upgrade: Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, upgrade

I'm almost done upgrading Cocos2D from 0.99.5 to 2.1, but I don't know how to resolve this error. This is what shows up as the error:

**Ld /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flying\ Adventure.app/Flying\ Adventure normal i386
    cd /Users/Admin/Documents/EriksFiles/Erik/iPad/cocos2d/flyingAdventure/flyingAdventure_current
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Intermediates/flyingAdventure.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/flyingAdventure1.build/Objects-normal/i386/Flying\ Adventure.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lcocos2d\ libraries -framework CoreText -framework GameKit -lz.1.2.5 -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -lz -framework AVFoundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Intermediates/flyingAdventure.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/flyingAdventure1.build/Objects-normal/i386/Flying\ Adventure_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flying\ Adventure.app/Flying\ Adventure
ld: library not found for -lcocos2d libraries
Library not found for -lcocos2d libraries
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Does it have to do with my Link Binary With Libraries? Here's what that looks like:

[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

Comment: avoid using spaces in library names (change target's product name), with a bit of luck that may even fix this issue

Comment: It did not. Any other ideas? :(

Comment: try to build the library seperately (select the cocos2d lib scheme), sometimes Xcode doesn't display errors in dependent library targets only if you build them directly

Comment: So your saying only have cocos2d libraries checked in manage schemes? I tried that, and took about 10th of a second to build. If I check my app name along with the cocos2d libraries I get the errors again. Sometimes after I only have the cocos2d libraries checked and recheck my app name and try to build & run, it says "There is nothing built for scheme "cocos2d libraries"

Comment: I see what you mean by only selecting the cocos2d library. But yes, same errors after I successfully built the library alone, and then go back to my app name.

Comment: I just realized the structure of the "Build" folder mentioned in the details is very different than the one in my project folder. That probably matters right?

Comment: No, not normally. But you can do one thing, navigate to this folder in Finder: /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingAdventure-esbllafxkpvprvdfdsnfuyectjnh/Build/Products and delete all subfolders. Then build the cocos2d library target, does it create a subfolder there? Then build your app, does it create the app files in the same folder as the cocos2d library? It's possible your cocos2d library target outputs the files to a different location than normal, if so check build settings.

Comment: When building the library target alone, it does not create a subfolder there. Only when building the app does it create the subfolders. Are the Build Locations in Build Settings the place to look? Because for the Cocos2D libraries and the app, they are the same.

Comment: the cocos lib builds without errors? Have you checked whether the target contains any files in the compile sources phase? Try deleting the DerivedData folder, then build cocos, then check which files are created.

Comment: Yes, the cocos lib builds without errors. There's 277 files in the compile sources phase. I deleted the DerivedData folder, and built the cocos lib and files were created. What am I looking for?

Comment: Good question. Maybe check that the cocos lib target is listed under target dependencies, too.

Comment: Yes I see Cocos2d libraries. Maybe since this is an upgrade from Cocos 0.99.5 to 2.1, I didn't do a step where I'm supposed to upgrade the library? I also noticed when I start a new Cocos2D template, a library isn't listed in the targets or listed in the Link Binary with Libraries.